# Convert a relation SQL table into JSON using R

Tags: sql, json, r, nested

I'm attempting to convert a SQL table into JSON nested format using R. I can import the table into R easily. The problem is now getting all the parent-children relation in the JSON format. I already manage to have some kind of JSON output, but only list all parent individuals with respective children in the following form: ( i will just list the first 6 lines of the table)

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": ["a"],
      "children": ["b"]
    },
    {
      "name": ["b"],
      "children": ["c"]
    },
    {
      "name": ["c"],
      "children": ["d"]
    },
    {
      "name": ["b"],
      "children": ["e"]
    },
    {
      "name": ["e"],
      "children": ["f"]
    }
  ]
]
```

with

```
library(RJSONIO)
orgTable=orgTable[,c("Manager","ID")]
makeList<-function(x){
    if(ncol(x)>2){
        listSplit = split(x[-1],x[1],drop=T)
        lapply(names(listSplit),function(y){list(name=y,children=makeList(listSplit[[y]]))})
    }
    else{
        lapply(seq(nrow(x[1])),function(y){list(name=x[,1][y],children=x[,2][y])})
    }
}

jsonOut = toJSON(list(makeList(orgTable[2:6,])),pretty=TRUE)
cat(jsonOut)
```

The SQL table is:

```
Parent     Children
a          b
b          c
c          d
b          e
e          f
```

What I would like to obtain would be something like:

```
   {
    "name": "a",
    "children": [
        {
        "name": "b",
        "children": [
            {
            "name": "c",
            "children": [
                {
                "name": "d"
                }
                ]
            },
            {
            "name": "e",
            "children": [
                {
                "name": "f"
                }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help? If possible if I could add also info from a third column would be perfect.

The code I present comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818864/how-to-write-to-json-with-children-from-r) but was slightly tweaked for my needs.
I'm still quite new at R so please bear with me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with a simple recursive solution that only gets parent/children with no other attributes.

```
#get some help from igraph
library(igraph)

df <- read.table(
  textConnection(
'
Parent     Children
a          b
b          c
c          d
b          e
e          f
' )
  , header = TRUE
  , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

el_in <- get.adjlist(graph.data.frame(df),mode="in")
# fill in name/id instead of number
el_in <- lapply(
  el_in,
  function(x){
    names(el_in)[x]
  }
)

get_children <- function( adjlist, node ){
  names(Filter(function(x) x==node,unlist(el_in)))
}

recurse_tree <- function( adjlist, node = NULL ){
  #  start at root if undefined
  #    root will be the node with no in
  if(is.null(node)) node <- names(Filter(function(x)length(x)==0,adjlist))

  children <- get_children( adjlist, node )
  if(length(children)>0){
    list(
      name = node
      ,children = lapply(
        children
        ,function(x){
          recurse_tree( adjlist, x )
        }
      )
    )
  } else {
    list(
      name = node
    )
  }
}


jsonlite::toJSON(
  recurse_tree( el_in ),
  auto_unbox=T
)
```

Probably not the most efficient, but here is a solution using `data.tree` and `igraph` to build our hierarchy.

```
#get some help from the relatively new data.tree
#devtools::install_github("gluc/data.tree")
library(data.tree)
#get some help from igraph
library(igraph)

df <- read.table(
  textConnection(
'
Parent     Children
a          b
b          c
c          d
b          e
e          f
' )
  , header = TRUE
  , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

#this will be our paths for data.tree
build_path <- function(df){
  g <- graph.data.frame(df)
  #get an adjacency list of all in
  el_in <- get.adjlist( g, mode="in" )
  tree <- lapply(el_in,function(x){""})
  lapply(
    1:length(el_in)
    ,function(n){
      id <- names(el_in)[n]
      x <- el_in[[n]]
      if(length(x)>0){
        tree[[id]] <<- paste0(
          tree[[el_in[[id]]]],
          "/",
          id
        )
      } else {
        tree[[id]] <<- id
      }
    }
  )
  return(unlist(tree))
}


tree <- as.Node(data.frame(
  pathString = build_path(df),
  # have the ability to specify values
  #  if not then just set NA
  value = NA,
  stringsAsFactors = F
))

jsonlite::toJSON(
  as.list( tree, mode="explicit", unname = TRUE),
  auto_unbox = TRUE
)

# as a test let's build a random tree with igraph
tree_grf <- graph.tree(n=10,children=3)
plot(tree_grf)
tree <- as.Node(data.frame(
  pathString = build_path(
    get.data.frame(tree_grf,what="edges")
  ),
  # have the ability to specify values
  #  if not then just set NA
  value = NA,
  stringsAsFactors = F
))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @timelyportfolio . I am trying to run your code but I am probably missing a package since I get the following errors: Error: could not find function "as.Node" and Error: No method asJSON S3 class: name

Comment: you'll have to do `devtools::install_github("gluc/data.tree")`.  If you don't have `devtools`, then see https://github.com/hadley/devtools#updating-to-the-latest-version-of-devtools.

Comment: After installing the data.tree package, I load the package and get:`Error : cannot allocate vector of size 2.8 Gb` by only running the `library(data.tree)`

Comment: I'll add to my answer a non data.tree solution.

Comment: It's working right now!!! I had to install the Rtools from the github and now it is working :) Thank you very much, I really appreciated all you quick responses.

Comment: did the non data.tree also work for you?  I am thinking about extending into a more robust function.  Happy to help.  Keep up the R.

Comment: I'm sorry for not replying but I didn't get the notification. I only tried the data.tree example. Is this approach more advisable?

Comment: either works fine; I was just trying to give a couple ways of doing.

Comment: OK then. Once again, thank you so much for all the help! :)