# Parsing output of r getTree() to JSON

Tags: json, r, d3.js

I have R code that gets one tree out of the random forest algorithm as follows:

```
testp.rf <- randomForest(new.df, group5, ntree = numoftree, 
        importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE)
tree <- getTree(testp.rf, k=1, labelVar=TRUE)
```

It returns a data frame that looks like the below table screenshot. I would like to turn this into a JSON format with the correct tree hierarchy similar to the one used for [this D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4347473). What is the quickest way to parse the R data frame into this JSON structure.

[image]

UPDATE: I added a "parents" column to the data frame to use it as a factor, wrote the data frame to a flat JSON that looks like:

```
 [{
"name": 1,
"parent": 0,
"left": 2,
"right": 3,
"split_var": "200862_at",
"split_point": 10.3106,
"isLeaf": 1,
"prediction": "NA"
}, /*...*/ 
]
```

then used the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818864/how-to-write-to-json-with-children-from-r) to parse it in my JS to the hierarchical form that can create a d3.layout.partition.
The resulting tree structure looks something like this:

```
 {
"name": "1",
"parent": "0",
"left": "2",
"right": "3",
"split_var": "200862_at",
"split_point": "10.3106",
"isLeaf": "1",
"prediction": "NA",
"children": [{
    "name": "2",
    "parent": "1",
    "left": "4",
    "right": "5",
    "split_var": "207708_at",
    "split_point": "7.212135",
    "isLeaf": "1",
    "prediction": "NA",
    "children": [{ /*...*/ 
     /*...*/
 }
```

However,this is still missing important decision tree information like the rules and size of each node. The desired output should look something like the following JSON which I parsed from [rpart](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf) output:

```
{
"name": "1",
"rule": "",
"children": [{
    "name": "2",
    "rule": "200862_at < 10.3106",
    "children": [{
        "name": "3",
        "rule": "200862_at < 10.3106 & 207708_at < 7.212135",
        "children": [{
            "name": "4",
              /*...*/
 }]
```

I am doing the tree generation in R and parsing in JS but I'm open to solutions in any of the two.

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818864/how-to-write-to-json-with-children-from-r ?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. No the example you pointed out considers one column as a factor for another. I found a few ways to build the JSON hierarchy from grouping rows in  a data frame based on factors like this, but none that take the structure that is obtained from getTree which has no such factors.

Comment: Can you add to your question what your expected output would be?  Also, are you looking for an answer in JavaScript or R?

Comment: @Mark I edited the question to show the desired output as opposed to what I currently have. I am now able to draw an icicle plot in D3 from the hierarchical JSON I copied above but it's missing important information like the list of rules and the size of each node which renders an inaccurate icicle plot. I need a way to add this information to the nodes as I traverse the tree.